# Options buying and selling on collectibles

Tags: finance, regulations

Could I legally create a website that allows for the purchase of options on collectibles – baseball cards, for example?  Let's assume it's on a collectible that fluctuates in value rather than consistently depreciates.  What regulation, if any, would I have to be aware of in creating this?

Comment: My *guess* is that, in the U.S., the SEC might assert authority to regulate, and you would then either have to register and comply with that agency or else tailor your market to a clearly defined exemption from SEC regulation.  One key question is whether you are, by the legal definition of the phrase, "making a market in securities."

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I figured contacting them first is probably a good idea.

Comment: @feetwt the SEC has jurisdiction over options on securities - these are options on personal property.

Answer (score 3):

This would appear to be a simple application of contract law - the exchange of money for a promise (to sell at a fixed price in the future). Option contracts are only regulated if they relate to options over securities (like company shares) - not if they are over personal property (like baseball cards).